# Combinatorial approach to prove divisibility results with the sequence $u_{n+p+1} = u_{n+p} + u_{n}$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, finite-fields, combinatorial-proofs

For a fixed prime number $p$, we consider the sequence :
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
u_n = 1, & 0\leq n \leq p \\
u_{n+p+1} = u_{n+p} + u_n
\end{array}\right.
$$
I want to prove that $\forall a \in \mathbb{N},\ p|u_{pa}-u_a$

**My attempt :**

I think that there are two natural approaches to tackle this problem:

- One way is to apply results about linear sequences, but i'm not very familiar with how it should be done in the field $\mathbb{F}_p$.
  We thus consider the characteristic polynomial $Q(X) := X^{p+1}-X^p-1$ in the field $\mathbb{F}_p$. One can easily check that $Q'(X) = X^p$ and has only $0$ as a root, which is not a root of $Q(X)$, thus every roots of $Q(X)$ are simple.

If we could say that $u_n = \sum_{k} \lambda_k\alpha_k^n$ with $\alpha_k$ roots of $Q(X)$, then we would be done by Fermat's theorem.

My problem is that I think that $Q(X)$ has at most $2$ roots, that are those of $X^2-X-1$ (and actually we would need that $5$ is a square $mod(p)$, ie. that $p$ must be either $1\ mod(5)$ or $-1\  mod(5)$ by quadratic reciprocity)

- The second approach is more combinatorial, and use the fact that $u_n$ can be interpreted as the number of ways one can tile a $(p+1)\times n$ rectangle with $(p+1)\times 1$ dominos. Indeed the relationship can be derived by observing that a $(p+1)\times(n+p+1)$ tiling is either a $(p+1)\times(n+p)$ tiling with a vertical domino filing the last slice, or a $(p+1)\times n$ tiling with $(p+1)$ horizontal domino filing the remaining square.

If we consider a $(p+1)\times pa$ rectangle, then we can "naturally" slice it in $p$ rectangles of size $(p+1)\times a$. There are $u_a^p$ ways of tiling the initial rectangle with dominos that doesn't "cut" a small rectangle. By Fermat's theorem, we need to show that the number of tilings $v_{pa}$ having a domino that "cut" a small rectangle is a multiple of $p$, because we would have $u_{pa} = u_a^p + v_{pa} = u_a\ mod(p)$.

I don't know how to show this. The ideal proof would be to find an action splitting the possible tilings into $p$ orbits of the same size for example. I also tried to explicit $v_{bp}$ with the inclusion-exclusion principle (but I assumed $a\geq 2p$ so that's not very satisfying):

If we note the inner vertical edges of the small rectangles from left to right by $1,\dots,p-1$ we can try to split by the events $A_j = \{ \text{tilings with a domino cuting the edge}\ j\}$ and I found, if not mistaken:
$$
v_{pa} = \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}(-1)^{k-1}\sum_{1\leq i_1 \leq \dots \leq i_k \leq p-1}\ \sum_{n^k \in \{1,\dots,p\}^k}\ \prod_{j=1}^{k+1}(u_{i_j a - (p+1-n_{j-1}^k+n_j^k)})
$$
with the boundary conditions $i_{k+1} = p-\sum_{j=0}^k i_j$ and $n_0^k = n_{k+1}^k = 0$, but I'm not sure we can make something out of it.

Because I haven't got a proof of this result, anything would be welcomed but I'm particularly curious about where the combinatorial approach would lead as it seems more elementary.

Comment: You proved that the zeros $\alpha_k$ of $Q(X)$ are simple, so surely there are $p+1$ of them. Most of them belong to an extension field of $\Bbb{F}_p$, and are thus Galois conjugates of each other. But, the entries of the sequence obviously stay in the prime field. This implies that the coefficients $\lambda_k$ associated to conjugate roots must be equal. Uniqueness of the solution of the recurrence already implies that. Your claim then follows immediately from the fact that the Galois group is generated by the Frobenius automorphism $\alpha\mapsto \alpha^p$.

Comment: In other words, if $\alpha$ is a root of $Q(X)$, $\alpha^p$ is another, $\alpha^{p^2}$ yet another, and sooner or later we have $\alpha^{p^m}=\alpha$. If $m$ is the first exponent for which that happens, then it follows that this set of zeros of $Q(X)$ gives a contribution $\sum_i \lambda_i(\alpha^{p^i})^n$ to $u_n$, and furthermore $\lambda_i$s must all be equal *for any initial segment of values $u_0,u_1,\ldots,u_p$ from the prime field $\Bbb{F}_p$*. All the zeros of $Q(X)$ form groups of conjugates like that (the zeros in the prime field are singleton sets).

Comment: By Freshman's dream it follows that for all $a$ we have $u_{pa}=u_a^p=u_a$, the last equality by Little Fermat.

Comment: I can flesh that out to an answer, but for it to be helpful to you I need to ask whether you know any Galois theory and/or theory of extension fields of $\Bbb{F}_p$?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @JyrkiLahtonen, I was pretty sure it was possible to save the first approach with more knowledge. Actually, I only know the basic principles of Galois Theory. I'm ok with considering an extension $\mathbb{L}$ in which $Q$ has $p+1$ simple roots. The fact that the $\lambda_i$s are equal by unicity of decomposition is also fine (but I'm not sure about the meaning of your remark between asterisks).

Comment: I didn't know the part about Frobenius automorphism generating the Galois Group, I'm not sure about why $\alpha^{p^m}$ would cycle back to $\alpha$ and not just another $\alpha^{p^n}$. Otherwise, from this I can conclude by saying that in each group:
$$\sum_{i}\lambda_i(\alpha^{p^i})^{pa} = \lambda \sum_{i=0}^m (\alpha^{p^{i+1}})^a = \lambda\sum_{i}(\alpha^{p^i})^a
$$
Great! On the other hand, do you have any idea about a proof exploiting the combinatorial interpretation of this sequence ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I would like to propose additional solutions to the problem, that should be a little bit more elementary in the sense that they don't require extension fields of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

We will use a slightly different combinatorial interpretation of the sequence: for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $u_n$ is the number of possible tilings of a $1\times n$ rectangle using $1\times 1$ dominos and $1\times (p+1)$ dominos (simply consider a horizontal slice of the $(p+1)\times n$ rectangle). Using this interpretation, we will refer to the $1\times 1$ dominos as the "short" dominos and the $1\times (p+1)$ dominos as the "long" dominos.

- First proof (based on arithmetic identities):

The idea is that we can derive the following closed form of $u_n$ :
$$
u_n = \sum_{k\geq 0} \binom{n-pk}{k}
$$
assuming that $\binom{n}{k} = 0$ whenever $k > n$.
This can be proved with the combinatorial interpretation in the following way:

Partition the set of possible tilings of a $1 \times n$ rectangle according to the number of long dominos a tiling is using.
Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ be given.
In order to construct a tiling using $k$ long dominos, one need to use $n-(p+1)k$ short dominos, so it amounts to select the position of the $k$ long dominos among the total of $n-pk$ dominos.
In other words, there are $\binom{n-pk}{k}$ possible tilings of the $1\times n$ rectangle that use $k$ long dominos.
Summing over all $k\geq 0$ gives the identity.

We therefore have in particular that
$$
\forall a \in \mathbb{N},\ u_{pa} = \sum_{k\geq 0} \binom{p(a-k)}{k}
$$

We will now use the following arithmetic lemma:
$$
\begin{align*}
  \binom{pn}{k}  &= 0\ mod(p) \quad \text{if $p$ does not divide $k$}\\
  \binom{pn}{pk} &= \binom{n}{k}\ mod(p)
\end{align*}
$$
It is an immediate consequence of Lucas's theorem, but we can also rederive it by considering the following polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{pn} \binom{pn}{k} X^k &= (1+X)^{pn} \ mod(p) \\
  &= ((1+X)^p)^n \ mod(p)\\
  &= (1+X^p)^n \ mod(p)\\
  &= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} X^{pk}\ mod(p)
\end{align*}
$$
identifying the coefficient of each monomial gives the identity.
Thus it follows that
$$
\begin{align*}
u_{pa} &= \sum_{k\geq 0} \binom{p(a-k)}{k} \\
  &= \sum_{k\geq 0} \binom{p(a-pk)}{pk} \ mod(p) \\
  &= \sum_{k\geq 0} \binom{a-pk}{k} \ mod(p) \\
  &= u_a \ mod(p)
\end{align*}
$$
Which gives a first proof of the result.

- Second proof (based on combinatorics/group actions):
  Let us note by $v_n$ the number of possible tilings of the $1\times n$ rectangle where we are eventually allowing the first long domino to be cut in order to fill the beginning and the end of the rectangle (in a sense, we are considering tilings of the $1 \times n$ cylinder).
  By considering the way to place the first domino, we clearly have
  $$
  \left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
    v_n = 1, & 0\leq n \leq p\\
    v_{n+p+1} = u_{n+p} + (p+1)u_n&
  \end{array}\right.
  $$
  In other words, $(v_n)$ and $(u_n)$ satisfy the same recurrence relation in $\mathbb{F}_p$ so they must be equal modulo $p$.
  However, note that we can build a simple $\mathbb{F}_p$-action on the set of tilings of the $1 \times pa$ cylinder for $a\in \mathbb{N}$:
  cut the rectangle into $p$ rectangular blocks of size $1 \times a$ and permute the block cyclically (it is clear that it gives valid tiling if you see this as a rotation of the cylinder by $a$ units).
  Now the orbits of every tiling (ie. the tilings obtained when applying multiple times this cyclic permutation to a tiling) must be of size $p$ or $1$ because $p$ is prime.
  The orbits of size $1$ corresponds to the tilings that are fixed by the rotation, therefore they are composed of $p$ times the same block, corresponding to a tiling of a $1\times a$ cylinder.
  Therefore there are $v_a$ orbits of size $1$.
  Finally, we can conclude by regrouping tilings by orbits that
  $$
  u_{pa} = v_{pa} = v_a = u_a \ mod(p)
  $$
  which again concludes the proof.